# why do i get ValueError: width and height must each be below 32768 after annotations?

Tags: python, matplotlib, annotate

I'm getting very confused by this error, because I'm running a code that was working on the same data I've already used.
The only thing I changed was adding these two lines to annotate different areas of the plot:

```
plt.annotate('first group',xy=(100000, position1),size='x-large',ha='center',va='top',bbox=dict(alpha=0.5,facecolor='white',boxstyle='round'))
plt.annotate('second group',xy=(100000,NOJU[10]['n0/'][-1000]),size='x-large',ha='center',va='top',bbox=dict(alpha=0.5,facecolor='white',boxstyle='round'))
```

where 100000 is half of the length of the x axis. If i delete these lines I don't get the error anymore, how is this possible? I have no clue and I need to annotate the plot...

Thank you!

Comment: The error is saying that your resultant image is  >32k pixels in one or both axes. If you were only just below that size before, perhaps your annotation is being placed outside the axes and pushing the size over this limit? You could try hard-coding the Y coordinate as well as the X and see if you still get the same error. Do both lines, individually, cause the error?

Comment: This is a limitation due to the way the `Agg` render works underneath.  Can you provide a minimal example which generates the error?